# A full explanation for the ResolvedFileToPublish XML element?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, single-page-application, csproj

By default, the ASP.NET Core SPA project templates have a section in their `.csproj` files like so:

```
<!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
<ItemGroup>
  <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
  <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
  <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
    <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```

I'm not finding any good documentation for this on Google, but I think this section might help me with what I want to do.  I want to modify it for my own purposes but first I need to fully understand it, so could someone explain to me the following:

- Where does `SpaRoot` get set?
- What exactly does `ResolvedFileToPublish` do?
- Where does `DistFiles` get set?
- Where does `FullPath` get set?
- What does the `@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)'` "arrow notation" mean?
- What does `Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)"` do?
- What does `DistFiles.Identity` refer to and where does it get set?

**UPDATE:** This page gives some documentation on this item but not much:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#selective-file-inclusion

Comment: It is a bit hard to answer the question as it is very broad, asking deep details of the publish process together with basic msbuild language/syntax. An exhaustive answer would basically need to quote half of the documentation at [MSBuild Concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-concepts?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I'm sure it'd be possible to give some concise, bullet-point answers to the specific questions without going into reams of detail.

Comment: To answer one of my own questions: `DistFiles` gets set by the `<DistFiles...` XML elements, and apparently consists of a semicolon-delimited list of full paths to files that have been specified in the `<DistFiles...` elements' `Include` attributes.  The `Include` attribute works in this way in this instance (pulling in files to include in the build process), because that attribute is specifically treated that way by MSBuild when attached to an element inside an `ItemGroup` parent.

Comment: I suggest you use this tool https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog it's better than any documentation (that will *not* exist for every property) it's hierarchical, searchable, etc. https://twitter.com/KirillOsenkov/status/1052051332532600837 It's a must when one wants to get serious with msbuild

Comment: thanks for asking this question...it's like MS didn't realize they could put comments in their confusing build targets for n00bs like me.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> Where does `SpaRoot` get set?

`SpaRoot` is set as a property in the project by the template.
Projects contain a "static" portion; that is root-level `PropertyGroup` and `ItemGroup` elements.

Note that properties are like a global key-value dictionary (and whenever an XML node in a `PropertyGroup` defines a property, it overwrites existing ones with the same name).
Items however are like lists; you can add (`<MyItem Include="..."/>`), remove (`... Remove="..."`) and even update items (`... Update="..."` in static portions only, no include/remove inside targets means "update all" which you can only filter with a `Condition` attribute). Items are like objects, they have an "ID" which is called "Identity" and can have other properties, which are called "metadata". The "Identity" is the part that is specified in `Include`, which may or may not be a file name. If a file is referenced, some well-known metadata is added automatically (such as file modification dates and `FullPath`). Metadata can also be defined on item XML elements as either attributes (e.g. as seen in `Version="1.2.3"` on PackageReference items) or as child elements of the item element (e.g. `RelativePath` as seen above).

> What exactly does ResolvedFileToPublish do?

The build is executed in the build engine by running targets that contain logic. All of the build logic that .NET projects run are controlled from MSBuild code that uses the same syntax as the project file. So by using imports or SDKs, the `.csproj` file itself is a build definition rather than a configuration file. Using mechanisms like `BeforeTargets`/`AfterTargets`, one can hook into the build process at specific points to execute code; in this case, the template contains a target that hooks into the publish logic.

`ResolvedFileToPublish` itself doesn't do anything special. The XML elements tell msbuild to add items to the `ResolvedFileToPublish` list based on file specifications, one of them only if the project is configured with server-side rendering (which is a property that AFAIK is also present in the static portion of the project in the template).

At a later stage during the build, targets coming from the .NET SDK use these items to compute files to copy during publish operations, tool packaging, and/or single-file publishing (3.0 feature), see [Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/fe6b50c78426124e34e56ecb7df8b6b86e6e0b48/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets) for the code that uses `@(Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets)` to access the list of items.

It is a convention that whenever properties or items are used by Microsoft-/3rd-party build logic that do not start with underscores (`_`), those are allowed/expected to be configured via build customizations, such as provided in the SPA templates. So we are meant to add `ResolvedFileToPublish` items which are considered "public API", but not `_ResolvedFileToPublishAlways`. By adding the built SPA files as items, we can tell the publish logic to include them during publish.

> Where does DistFiles get set?

`DistFiles` is created by this template / logic itself. There is next to no restriction on which item or property names can be used. This could also have been named `SpaDistFiles` or similar. The template creates some intermediate items it can later use to create `ResolvedFileToPublish` items and hopes that the name doesn't conflict with any other name used in build logic.

> Where does FullPath get set?

Full path is an automatic well-known property that msbuild adds to items that reference files on disk.

While an item's identity could be `ClientApp\dist\myapp\index.html` (or relative paths containing `..\`), its `FullPath` metadata will be `C:\path\to\proj\ClientApp\....`.

> What does the @(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)' "arrow notation" mean?

While properties can be accessed using the `$()` syntax, items are referenced using `@()`.

When you have item `MyItem` with identities `A` and `B`, `@(MyItem)` (when evaluated to text) would be `A;B`. This could again be interpreted as an item specification, so passed to `<OtherItem Include="@(MyItem)" />`.

But the `@()` syntax also allows for item transformations or calling item functions (`@(MyItem->Count())`). Transformation is a projection of each item to another item, so in this example, `@(MyItem->'X')` would result in `X;X` since both items are transformed to the same value. To include parts of the original item, metadata values can be accessed via `%()`. So `@(MyItem->'Hello %(Identity)')` would result in `Hello A;Hello B`, since `Identity` is default metadata.

In this case, the `DistFiles` items which contain the path relative to the project file are transformed to reference the full path. While this is not well documented, this is needed since publishing logic expects `ResolvedFileToPublish` items to contain an absolute/full path since it can also be flown across project references - e.g. a library could contain publish-only assets and the consuming project needs to copy them during publish so it needs to pass the full path and not the relative path, which would not be found in the consuming project.

> What does Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)" do?

An item `Include="..."` can be filtered to not add items that are part of the `Exclude` definition.
In this case, the action translates to "Add the full path of `DistFiles` items as `ResolvedFileToPublish` items unless there is already an `ResolvedFileToPublish` item with the same identity (i.e. referring to the same file on disk)".

This is useful so as to not confuse the publish logic with duplicate items. Not sure at the moment if this would actually cause problems, but in order to be a good citizen, it is better not to cause additional file copies / file uploads (web deploy) etc.

The reason the files could already be in there is that they may have already been included by one of the default item specifications defined in the Web SDK that includes e.g. files in `wwwroot` or similar for publishing, depending on how your project is set up. The template just doesn't want to cause conflicts.

> What does DistFiles.Identity refer to and where does it get set?

As mentioned above, items have some default metadata and `Identity` is one of them. In this case, the `DistFiles` items are created from file specifications relative to the project, so the item's identities are the project-relative paths (`ClientApp\dist\...`).

Since `ResolvedFileToPublish` items contain absolute paths, the `RelativePath` metadata tells the publish logic where to place the file during publish. You could also use this to rename the files or place them in subfolders.

In a verbose log / structured log, you should see that the items being added are `C:\path\to\proj\ClientApp\dist\index.html` with `RelativePath=ClientApp\dist\index.html` and `CopyToPublishDirectory=PreserveNewest` metadata.

### Item batching

In the above code, there is a reference to metadata from within an attribute:

```
<RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
```

While this tells MSBuild to set the `RelativePath` metadata to the source `DistFiles` item's `Identity`, this also triggers a feature called [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-metadata-in-task-batching?view=vs-2019).

For every loose `%(Item.Metadata)` specification MSBuild sees (note that this only works inside targets) MSBuild groups the referenced item(s) into "batches" having the same property. It then runs the task that this is used in (in our case an intrinsic item add task) once for each batch, in which the `@()` notation will only yield the items from that particular batch.

When only batching on `%(XYZ.Identity)`, this doesn't really matter and can be seen as a simple "for all".

So to be exact, the `<ResolvedFileToPublish Include=...` part would translate to: "For each set of DistFiles with the same `Identity` metadata, transform these items to their full path and, unless a `ResolvedFileToPublish` with this file name already exists, create a `ResolvedFileToPublish` item for them with the metadata `RelativePath` set to the DistFile item's `Identity` value, and the `CopyToPublishDirectory` metadata set to `PreserveNewest`."

Comment: Thanks, great answer.  Just one thing (you might wanna update the answer with this): `ResolvedFileToPublish` is singular.  Is this just a typo?  It seems like it's a collection of files.  Shouldn't it be `ResolvedFilesToPublish`?

Comment: Sadly there is no standard convention for singular/plural naming. While the items do form a collection of similar things, you could also refer to individual ones. `ResolvedFileToPublish` is singular as defined in the linked targets file, but other items are named in various ways - sometimes this makes sense (single .config file) and sometimes not so much (ResolvedFileToPublish)

Comment: Also added a description of batching which is used here, though not so obvious.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I've fixed a few typos; the only one I couldn't figure out was "took packaging" in the phrase "compute files to copy during publish operations, took packaging and/or single-file publishing".  Could you edit it to say what you actually meant?  I assume it's a typo.

Comment: Tool packaging - when you set `PackAsTool` to true to create .NET Core global/local tools.

Comment: Microsoft decided to kill the world. Why it is so complicated ???

Comment: Great guide. @MartinUllrich  you mentioned that "You could also use this to rename the files or place them in subfolders." when talking about RelativePath. How could I do this in a 'dynamic' way, e.g. tell the build to publish all files to a folder that's relative from '%(DistFiles.Identity)' ?

Comment: I'd suggest trying `<RelativePath>subfolder\%(DistFiles.RelativeDir)%(DistFiles.FileName)%(DistFiles.Extension)</...>`. Maybe open a new questions if that doesn't work out

Comment: This is an incredible answer, thank you! For anyone else coming here, this is the reference for properties of DistFiles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2019

Comment: I wanted to include an Angular app from another directory. I had to use `RecursiveDir` instead of `RelativeDir` because I use `**` inside `Include`.

`<DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\apps\my-app\**" />...<RelativePath>ClientApp\%(DistFiles.RecursiveDir)%(DistFiles.Filename)%(DistFiles.Extension)</RelativePath>...`